# How can I get a button in SharePoint to display info about a record?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a list in SharePoint 2013. One of the columns is a button, which I made by making the column a calculated field and using HTML to display a button. When the button is pressed, I want to add information from the record to which the button belongs to a different list.

I am using jQuery and [SharePointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/index.html) to add information to a different list and that part is working fine.

The part I cannot get is how to pull information from the specific record to add to the other list. Can anyone help?

Here is the code that fires when a button is pressed:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sharepointplus/3.0.7/sharepointplus.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function addToBasket() {
alert('started');


var vn = $("input[title='Artifact Name']").val(); //returns undefined

alert(vn);

$SP().list("ListOfPicturesRequested").add({RequestID:"4",ImageRequested:vn});

alert('done');
}
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: So your button shows in the AllItems.aspx for example? Or similar view? Is that correct? Or do you use it in a form ? Because what are you trying to get with `$("input[title='Artifact Name']").val()` ? Also what information your button has ? ... Too much information are missing here to help :-/

Comment: @AymKdn Yes, the button is in the AllItems.aspx of a list. Each record in this list has its own button. When a button is pressed, I want information from that record in which the button is pressed to be added to a completely different list. I successfully added info to another list, I just don't know how to pull info from the list where the buttons are in.

Comment: We need more details/code. I guess you need to have the item ID related to the button, to then get the data you need and deal with them. To do so, you can insert the Item ID in your HTML code for the button. Your button code would look like that `<input type="button" data-id="1" value="Click me" class="mybuttons">`. Then use `$('.mybuttons').on('click',function() { /* do something with $(this).data('id') */ })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. So if each record in a list has its own button and you want to pass information from a record to a different list when a button is pressed, you need to have this code in the column where the buttons appear:

```
=CONCATENATE("<input type='button' name='btnAddToBasket' id='btnAddToBasket' value='Add to basket' onclick=","addToBasket('",[Document Name],"','",[Original],"')"," />")
```

This way, when a button is pressed, specific data from that record can be passed on to a JavaScript function, which can then send that data to a different list.

Hope this helps someone out.